# Converting a steam hex into steam community id

Tags: lua, steam, fivem

I am using lua FiveM to get steam hex of a player but i want to convert that hex to a community id like 76561198364192600. How do i got about that? is there an api that can be used in this case.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under linux and with Lua 5.1 you can visit a webserver that is doing the job.

```
local STEAM_ID = 'STEAM_0:0:201963436'
local STEAM_ID64 = io.popen('wget -q --no-check-certificate -O- https://steamid.io/lookup/' .. STEAM_ID .. ' | grep -o -E "[0-9]{16,32}" | head -n1', 'r'):read('*a')

print(STEAM_ID64)
-- Output: 76561198364192600
```